# How to properly create Type definitions on Gatsby for external images

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am using Gatsby 3.6.1, with [Gatsby plugin image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image). I am fetching images from an API which returns the following structure:

```
[
   {
     "pk": 1,
     "url": "https://location_of_the_image1",
   },
       {
     "pk": 2,
     "url": "https://location_of_the_image2",
   },

]
```

These images are stored within the nodes `API__Image` and then I use `createRemoteFileNode` to create a local version of the file within the `API__Image.image` field:

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode },
  store,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `API__Image` && node.pk) {
    let fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.url, // string that points to the URL of the image
      parentNodeId: node.id, // id of the parent node of the fileNode you are going to create
      createNode, // helper function in gatsby-node to generate the node
      createNodeId: id => `IMG${node.pk}`,
      cache, // Gatsby's cache
      store, // Gatsby's Redux store
    })
    // if the file was created, attach the new node to the parent node
    if (fileNode) {
      node.image___NODE = fileNode.id
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this setup is that it returns the following error when using `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` more than once:

`Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type for: "image___NODE". There is no corresponding node with  the "id" field matching: "IMG286,IMG287...`

**How should I create a proper type definition for this code?** I have tried following the example of [this page](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/preprocessing-external-images/), but I keep getting the same error:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
  type API__Image implements Node {
    pk: ID!
    url: String!
    image: File @link(from: "image___NODE")

  }
`
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Another interesting question, why the node internal type is called `API__Image` but nonetheless when accessing GraphQL at `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` it is displayed as `apiImage`? Should I use `API__Image` or `apiImage` when defining the GraphQL Type?